# SSL Certificates and generating a CSR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, dns

Today I purchased a SSL certificate from GoDaddy for a URL which is under my same GoDaddy account.

I have no knowledge of using SSL certificates or setting them up.

I have a few questions I believe many people will be able to help with:

I have a domain that is not currently hosted using Heroku, although I will be setting the domain to work with Heroku and an app I'm working on. Can I set up the SSL and generate a CSR using the GoDaddy CPanel? And would the SSL certificate still work with the domain if I later started using Heroku? Or should I be doing it all via the Heroku servers?

Apologies I have read a few articles but I am still a little confused on these points. Here is the GoDaddy documentation that may be of interest.

https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5343/generating-a-certificate-signing-request?locale=en&countrysite=uk

Thanks.